# how to remove menu from fragment back pressed android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, menuitem, fragment-backstack

I am developing a application that should support on both phone and tablet.
In this application i am using fragments from android.

Now the flow of the application is like

**MainActivity --> Fragment1 --> Fragment2**

In this application , i want a menu item that should show only in Fragment2 along with activity's menu items.

So i have tried one solution like adding globle menu items in MainActivity and in Fragment2 replacing the whole MainActivity's menu with Fragment2 specific Menu.

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

inside onCreateView , and implement this method.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_f, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

Now its work exactly fine for phone layout , but when its come to tablet problem arise.

Here is my ScreenShots.

**Fragment 1**
[image]

**Fragment 1 and Fragment 2 combination when pressing 9 in keybord(Tablet mode ).**
[image]

**And Finally when i pressed 9 again to come back to pHone view it shows me extra menu item.**

[image]

I just marked a extra menu item in Image. So why this me coming and how can i resolve it ?

Comment: i guess in tablet mode both your fragments are visible. Is that the case ??

Comment: yes.bcz i need to show both fragments in tablet mode.
But when i nevigate back to mobile mode , the menu item should't be there

Comment: i guess this happening on a real device has a less chance. However, you should override the `onConfigurationChanged` and call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` or `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` which ever is appropiate

Comment: Firstly i tried to implement onConfigurationChanged() method for different proposes in fragment.
But it is not calling , don't know why :(

Comment: for `onConfigurationChanged` not getting called you have to set `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`  in the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the menu group like this in your `fragment 1`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

it'll make a call to `onPrepareOptionsMenu` where you can hide your menu group added by `fragment2`

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.setGroupVisible(0, false);
}
```

Comment: i tried this solution , but it is hiding mainactivity's menu.

Comment: look you need to keep the `fragment's` menu in a separate `menu group` got it? the menu items of `fragment1` `fragment2` and `fraagmentActivity` has to reside in different `menugroup`

Comment: ya i have tried this also.
Firstly its seems to be work fine , but once i navigate back to ( pressing 9) phone layout from tab layout , the group in not getting invisible.Its showing the group there to

Comment: <group android:id="@+id/fragment2g" android:visible="false">
        
         <item 
        android:id="@+id/addreview"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Add Review"
        android:icon="@drawable/add_preview"/>
        
    </group>

Comment: ya there it is working fine.
But problem creates when i switch from tab mode to mobile mode